# GORM Inheritance column definition mapping

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm

Hello evreyone,

I have two tables (A and B which extends A) . A and B are existing tables with an assigned Id. The Id (PK) is a String in A and B.

With GORM, I am unable to map these two tables if the common column between A and B is not the default one (column 'id' with Grails).

As an example =

```
class A {
    String acc;
    static mapping = {
        datasource 'xx'
        table "A"
        version false
        tablePerHierarchy false
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'acc'
        cache 'read-only'
    }

class B extends A {
    String acc;
    static mapping = {
        datasource 'xx'
        table "B"
        version false
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'acc'
        cache 'read-only'
}
```

What is wrong with the previous mapping please ?

1/ Grails generates an Id column in the B table which I don't want.
2/ I am unable to load a B object (since HQL links the column acc (table A) to the column id (new one in the table B)

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `column` argument to your id mapping:

```
id generator: 'assigned', name: 'acc', column: 'acc'
```

[Link to ref docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)